# Python httplib.HTTPSConnection and password

Tags: python, ssl, https, passwords, httplib

I use `httplib.HTTPSConnection` with private key:

```
h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url, key_file='../cert/priv.pem', cert_file='../cert/srv_test.crt')
```

Then I am asked to enter the password to that private key. Is there any option to enter such password not from user input (console) but from other source (code, environment)? Maybe something like in Java:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=my_secret_passwd
```

Comment: Have you tried to embed the pass into the url with typical syntax like:
`service://username:password@hostname:portnumber/filepath`
?

Comment: kai1968: this password is not for a website, but protects my private key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private key file is loaded in Python's _ssl module (the part that's written in C). From _ssl.c, line 333:

```
ret = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(self->ctx, key_file, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

This is an OpenSSL function which loads the given key file. If a password is provided, it will call a password callback function. As that function defaults to asking the user, you will have to override it using [`SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb.html). Unfortunately, this function is not included in the standard library or M2Crypto (Python OpenSSL wrapper), but you can find it in [pyopenssl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL).

In order to create a socket from a password-protected key file, you would have to do something like:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_passwd_cb(lambda *unused: "yourpassword")
ctx.use_privatekey_file(keyFilename)
ctx.use_certificate_file(certFilename)
someSocket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket())
```

Creating a HTTPS connection is a bit harder and I don't know how to do it with pyopenssl, but there's an example provided in pyopenssl's source code (test_ssl.py:242).

Comment: Thanks! I changed my client from `httplib.HTTPSConnection` to simple socket client with SSL support and it works!